# No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI hen revoking grants

Tags: tapkey

I have written a function to revoke grants issued for a boundlock as shown in the code snipped below:
For context, I first run a query to get all grants, and then use the ip
UserID to get the specific grant that I want to revoke:

```
  async revokeGrant (user) {
const token = await this.getAuthorizationCodeToken(this.refreshToken)
try {
  const { data: allGrants } = await axios.get(
    `${this.baseUrl}/owners/${this.operatorAccountId}/grants`,
    {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    }
  )
  const targetGrant = allGrants.find(grant => grant.contact.ipUserId === user.userId)
  // revoke grant after getting it from above
  const revokeResponse = await axios.post(
    `${this.baseUrl}/owners/${this.operatorAccountId}/grants/${targetGrant.id}/revoke`,
    {
      dryRun: true
    },
    {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    }
  )
  console.log('revokeResponse:', revokeResponse)
} catch (error) {
  throw errors.customError(
    error.response.data,
    platform.responseCodes.InternalServer,
    'Device Error',
    false
  )
}
```

}

I however keep running into an error:

```
      Message: "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://tapkey-prod-main-rs.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/owners/*********/grants/*********/revoke'."
    }
  },
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function]
}
```

Comment: Getting all grants and filtering the list locally can be quite expensive depending on the number of grants you have. You could also use OData filters to let the server do the filtering and only return the grants you need. Consider using something like `https://my.tapkey.com/api/v1/Owners/xxxxxxxx/Grants?$filter=contact/ipId eq 'yourIpId' and contact/ipUserId eq 'yourIpUserId'`. See https://developers.tapkey.io/openapi/tapkey_access_management_web_api_v1/#/Grants/Grants_GetAll.

Answer (score 1):

For revoking a grant the dryRun query parameter has to be added:
`https://tapkey-prod-main-rs.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/owners/*********/grants/*********/revoke?dryRun=false`

For more details please have a look at
https://developers.tapkey.io/openapi/tapkey_management_api_v1/#/Grants/Grants_RevokeById

Info:
The dryRun parameter is required. If omitted, the request will fail.

Please don't use `tapkey-prod-main-rs.azurewebsites.net` as baseUri as this is not a public hostname and might removed or changed without any notice.